# Executing an sql batch file within a seperate batch file

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, batch-file

I am running a 2008 `SQL server`. I am using remote backup to backup the server and have two batch files to trigger the backup process. The first batch file contains:

```
@echo off
CALL "" "C:\Scripts\SQL Maintainence\Nightly Maintenance 2008 SSE.bat"
```

The second batch file (Nightly Maintenance 2008 SEE) looks like this:

```
@echo off
osql -S %SERVER% -d msdb /U (username) /P (password) -i "Nightly Maintenance 2008 SSE.sql" -o "Nightly Maintenance 2008 SSE.txt"
```

For some reason, the first batch file is not calling for the second batch file to run, the script works when manually ran.

I am very new to writing batch files and have done quite a bit of research up to this point. Any help or maybe an article that can help with my issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have "" after CALL? Surely you just want to CALL "C:\...."

Comment: OSQL is a relic from SQL 2000.  By now you should be using SQLCMD.  Of course that is not your problem though.

Comment: Deleted my answer because Mark already answered above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Reposted as answer instead of question...*

I think you need to delete the "" immediately after the CALL, like this:

```
CALL "C:\Scripts\SQL Maintainence\Nightly Maintenance 2008 SSE.bat"
```